# Properly setting \thecounter when defining \newcounter{counter}[resetwith]

Tags: hyperref, counters, automation

With `\newcounter{counter}[resetwith]`, I can define a counter to be automatically reset when `resetwith` changes.

However, it seems that `\thecounter` is defined to just display the value of `counter`, and does not indicate the value of `resetwith` to which it is relative.

This has been dumbfounding to me because I am used to `\newtheorem{counter}{Display name}[resetwith]` to "properly" define things to get a coherent numbering of theorems.

Of course I can manually define `\thecounter` in a concrete case.

However I am writing a file that is to be included and used in several circumstances : which counter is `resetwith` *or whether there will be an automatic reset at all* depends on the context, so I am looking for an "upgraded" version of `\newcounter` that does what I need in a generic way.

Is there a "good" way to do this ?

Currently I am doing `\edef\@temp{\noexpand\newcounter{question}\resetlevel}\@temp` with `\resetlevel` a macro that expands to either nothing or the name of a counter between square brackets.

To spice things up, I am also using hyperref, and it seems to do some things with counter definitions.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thecounter}{\theresetwith.\arabic{counter}}`

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the definition of `\setcounter`; for the examples I'll use `\newcounter{foo}` and `\newcounter{foo}[baz]`.

```
% latex.ltx, line 2157:
\def\newcounter#1{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable \csname c@#1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@newctr{#1}}{}}
```

In order to see whether the counter has not yet been defined, LaTeX checks for `\c@foo` because, as we shall see, the name of the associated count register is obtained by prefixing the counter name with `c@`. If this is successful, `\@definecounter{foo}` is executed:

```
\def\@definecounter#1{\expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
     \setcounter{#1}\z@
     \global\expandafter\let\csname cl@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \@addtoreset{#1}{@ckpt}%
     \global\expandafter\let\csname p@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \expandafter
     \gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
```

The count register is allocated with `\newcount\c@foo` and, for safety, `\setcounter{foo}{0}` is issued.

Then a global macro `\cl@foo` is defined and initialized to be empty; it will hold the names of counters that should be reset when `foo` is stepped. Then the counter name is added to `\cl@ckpt`, the reset list of a dummy counter that's used during `\include` operations.

The global macro `\p@foo` is defined (the “prefix” when the counter value is printed) and initialized to empty.

Finally, `\thefoo` is globally defined to the default representation, basically `\arabic{foo}`.

If also the optional argument follows, as in the case of `\newcounter{foo}[baz]`, also `\@newctr{foo}[baz]` is executed.

```
% latex.ltx, line 2162:
\def\@newctr#1[#2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocounterr{#2}}{\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}}}
```

If `\c@baz` doesn't exist, an error is raised, as we'd be attempting to add `foo` to the reset list of a non existent counter. Otherwise `\@addtoreset{foo}{baz}` is performed, which actually appends `foo` to the reset list for `baz`.

Note that *no* redefinition of `\thefoo` happens in case the optional argument appears.

If you want that the representation of `foo` also depend on `baz`, you need to tell it explicitly; for instance

```
\newcounter{foo}[baz]
\renewcomand{\thefoo}{\thebaz.\arabic{foo}}
```

LaTeX is not clairvoyant and doesn't claim to be.

Why does `\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}[baz]` actually perform

```
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\thebaz.\arabic{foo}}
```

instead? Because most often people *wants* that theorems show the value of the counters the theorem is subordinate to. The most common call is like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

and it's widely expected that theorems are numbered like `<section>.<theorem>`.

I don't think you should go that complicated way when it's sufficient to remember issuing a suitable `\renewcommand{\thefoo}{...}` instruction.

A possibly better definition with a key-value system for maximum flexibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewCounter}{mO{}}
 {
  \group_begin: % to not clutter the values
  \keys_set:nn { ysalmon/newcounter } { #2 }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_ysalmon_newcounter_within_tl
   {
    \newcounter{#1}
    \cs_gset:cpx { the#1 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { \l_ysalmon_newcounter_repr_tl }
      { #1 }
     }
   }
   {
    \newcounter{#1}[\l_ysalmon_newcounter_within_tl]
    \cs_gset:cpx { the#1 }
     {
      \bool_if:NT \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_bool
       {
        \exp_not:c { the \l_ysalmon_newcounter_within_tl }
        \exp_not:V \l_ysalmon_newcounter_sep_tl
       }
      \exp_not:c { \l_ysalmon_newcounter_repr_tl }
      { #1 }
     }
   }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ysalmon_newcounter_also_clist
   {
    \counterwithin*{#1}{##1}
   }
  \tl_gset_eq:cN { p@#1 } \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { ysalmon/newcounter }
 {
  within  .tl_set:N    = \l_ysalmon_newcounter_within_tl,
  within* .code:n      = \keys_set:nn { ysalmon/newcounter } { whithin=#1 }
                         \bool_set_false:N \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_bool,
  also    .clist_set:N = \l_ysalmon_newcounter_also_clist,
  sep     .tl_set:N    = \l_ysalmon_newcounter_sep_tl,
  sep     .initial:n   = .,
  repr    .tl_set:N    = \l_ysalmon_newcounter_repr_tl,
  repr    .initial:n   = arabic,
  prefix  .tl_set:N    = \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_tl,
 }
\bool_new:N \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l_ysalmon_newcounter_prefix_bool

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewCounter{fooA}

\show\thefooA

\NewCounter{fooB}[
  repr=Roman,
]

\show\thefooB

\NewCounter{fooC}[
  repr=roman,
  sep=-,
  within=fooA
]

\show\thefooC

\NewCounter{fooD}[
  within*=fooB,
  also={section,subsection},
]

\show\thefooD
```

We define four counters and show their representation. The keys

1. `within` specifies a counter the present one should be subordinate to, with `\the<counter>` defined to be prefixed by the representation thereof
2. `within*` is the same, but no prefix is added to the representation
3. `also` specifies an optional list of counters the present one should be subordinate to (no addition to the representation)
4. `repr` should be one of `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, `Alph`, `fnsymbol` (or other counter representations you have defined)
5. `sep` is the separator between the “within” counter representation and the current counter one
6. `prefix` sets `\p@<counter>`

Here's the console output:

```
> \thefooA=\long macro:
->\arabic {fooA}.
l.51 \show\thefooA

? 
> \thefooB=\long macro:
->\Roman {fooB}.
l.57 \show\thefooB

? 
> \thefooC=\long macro:
->\thefooA -\roman {fooC}.
l.65 \show\thefooC

? 
> \thefooD=\long macro:
->\arabic {fooD}.
l.71 \show\thefooD
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that allows me to set the `\thecounter` appropriately with the following interface

```
\edef\@temp{\noexpand\setthe{question}\resetlevel}\@temp
```

**However I do not know yet how this behaves with hyperref.**

The definition of `\setthe` is

```
\def\setthe#1{\@ifnextchar[{\setthei{#1}}{}}
\def\setthei#1[#2]{%
\expandafter\let\expandafter\@temp\csname the#1\endcsname
\toks@\expandafter{\@temp}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#2\endcsname\@thmcountersep\the\toks@}}
```

The difficult point was to obtain the current meaning of `\csname the#1\endcsname` to upgrade it, but without fully expanding it (because it would expand to 0 at the beginning of the document and not update with the counter value).

`\@thmcountersep` in my definition is because I want to display the values like theorem numbers ; it can be replaced with eg. a dot.